# How to learn from which ip a successfull login has occured?

Tags: java, spring, unboxing

I use Spring Security 3. I have follewing method:

```
public class CustomUsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authResult) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.successfulAuthentication(request, response, authResult);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken) authResult;
        WebAuthenticationDetails details = (WebAuthenticationDetails) token.getDetails();
        String address = details.getRemoteAddress();
        System.out.println("Successful Login from remote address: "+ address);
    }

    @Override
    protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
        super.unsuccessfulAuthentication(request, response, failed);
        System.out.println("==failed login==");
    }
}
```

Do I have a dirty code for unboxing adress variable? Can I write it shortly or properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be probably better:

```
String address = request.getRemoteAddr();
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you looking for? That "address" will be the reported address of what/who requested your service, though it can be spoofed, and proxies will report themselves as the "remote address", optionally including an HTTP header including the original "remote address". By convention, the header is named "X-FORWARDED-FOR". It's completely up to the proxy and whoever configured it, though.